# How to filter processes by MEM% in Bash?

Tags: bash, ps

I've been given an assignment to print processes that are using 'x%' or more memory every 10 seconds.  The x% will come from an argument when executing the file.

(E.G. ./processes.sh 8 will print all processes using 8% or more memory every 10 seconds.)

I have no clue how to sort the processes by a specific memory parameter. I know how to sort the processes in ascending or descending order, just not how to print only the select processes that meet my criteria.  Here's a snippet of my code:

```
processes()
{
while :
do
        date
        echo "Processes occupying $1% of memory: "
        ps -o pid,user,%mem ax|sort -n -b -k3 -r|pgrep -f1 "$1"
        sleep 10
done
}

processes $1
```

I thought pgrep might be able to do it, but I think I either formatted it wrong, or it just doesn't work.

Ideally, the output should look like this:

```
Processes occupying 8% or more memory:
11452 kelly1653 13.6%
93612 buckley0003 29.6%
```

Any hints for me? I'm really frustrated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be all you need:

```
ps --no-headers -o pid,user,%mem |
    awk -v "arg=$1" '$3 >= arg {print $0 "%"}' |
    sort -nk 3
```

Use `awk` to select lines that have the third field value your argument or more, and to add the `%` which is missing from the `ps` output. Then sort numerically according to the third field.

Or with `ps` doing the sorting:

```
ps --no-headers -o pid,user,%mem --sort %mem |
    awk -v "arg=$1" '$3 >= arg {print $0 "%"}'
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this code as presented, but no matter the argument value I put in, there aren't any processes printing, even if I input the argument as 0 when executing the file.  Any idea why?

Comment: @Rocko Check what the `ps` part outputs on it's own.

Comment: I got it! I had to sort the data in a different way, for some reason awk was not reading in the %mem values properly.  Thank you so much!